# order by in only one query in UNION mysql

Tags: mysql, union

I have a table

Table **User**

```
 Id      Name     status        
 1       Jhon     Approved        
 2       Endy     Decline
 3       Ally     In Review
```

I have to show a list of all user and sort only those rows which are not approved.

My code is below

```
(select name from user where status<>'Approved' order by status asc)
UNION  
(select name from user where status='Approved')
```

I am always getting this on both cases `ASC` and `DESC`

```
Id      Name     status             
 3      Ally     In Review
 2      Endy     Decline
 1      Jhon     Approved
```

Should same result for order by `name` also.

```
(select name from user where status<>'Approved' order by name asc)
UNION  
(select name from user where status='Approved')

 Id      Name     status             
 3       Ally     In Review
 2       Endy     Decline
 1       Jhon     Approved
```

Please help me. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: And from the given data the expected result is ?

Comment: *but this query is not sorting.* .. the unapproved ones are put first, in alphabetical order by status (D, I) and the approved one is union'd on to the end. How is that not sorted?

Comment: I mean it gives same result in `ASC` and `DESC` case

Comment: *However, use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows.* - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html  that's why. Not sure what to get around it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case when` for the `order by`

```
select * from User 
order by  
case when status <> 'Approved' then 0 else 1 end ,status;
```

Comment: Not working ? Could you provide more information on that ?

Comment: Form the given data you outlined some experted resultset and the above query should do that, if you have some specific display pattern add them to the question.

Comment: Should same result for order by name also.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing union with union all, it works atleast in oracle

```
select * from 
(select * from t1 where status <> 'Approved' order by status asc)
union all
select * from 
(select * from t1 where status = 'Approved' )
```

output:

```
ID|NAME|STATUS
2|Endy|Declined
3|Ally|In Review
1|John|Approved
```

Hope it may help you. :)

Comment: your concern is only for union or (order clause in one query)  or both?
if it is only with Order clause in one query then union all will resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply. I got the solution

```
(select * from 
(select * from user where status <> 'Approved' order by status asc) a)
union 
(select * from t1 where status = 'Approved' )
```